# Как отправлять сообщения не дожидаясь получения сообщения от другого клиента?

Tags: python, сокет, асинхронность, tcp, p2p

В первый раз сталкиваюсь с socket в Python. Пишу простой P2P чатик, но не могу отправлять в нём сообщения после первого раза отправки(когда пользователь подключается к серверу, то отправляет один раз сообщение, а дальше начинает бесконечно ожидать получение сообщение от другого клиента), пытался разобраться с async, но что-то недопонял и не смог реализовать асинхронность
Код:

```
import socket
import sys 
import asyncio
import time

#Импорт библиотек


async def send_msg(s):
        while True:
            print('Please, write a message')
            msg = input().encode('UTF-8')
            if msg: #если на вход поступило сообщение, то кодируем его и отправляем
                msg_header = f"{len(msg):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('UTF-8')
                s.send(msg_header+msg)
                print(msg_header, msg)

async def recv_msg(s):
            while True:
                try: #Если нам поступает сообщение, содержащее заголовок, то принимаем его, показываем само сообщение и username того, кто отправил
                    user_header =s.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
                    if not len(user_header):
                        sys.exit()
                    user_lenght = int(user_header.decode('UTF-8').strip())
                    username = s.recv(user_lenght)

                    msg_header = s.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
                    msg_length = int(msg_header.decode('UTF-8').strip())

                    data = s.recv(msg_length).decode('UTF-8')
                    print(f"New message from {username.decode('UTF-8')} - {data}")
                except IOError as _ex:  
                    pass
#HEADER - const значение, ЗАГОЛОВОК
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
HOST_IP = input('Please, type IP of server')
HOST = HOST_IP,10000


async def main():
    username = input("Please type a username: ").encode('UTF-8')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(HOST)
    s.setblocking(False)

    header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('UTF-8')
    s.send(header + username)
```